# Filter data for a given day (timezone aware datetime) from postgres directly

Tags: django, postgresql

I want to filter all data for the following day (which is timezone aware).

**Assumptions:**

- server data is in a specific timezone
- client query is coming from different timezone

**My current approach is:**

```py
date = received_date_timezone_aware # any time of that day
lower = date.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0)
upper = lower + datetime.timedelta(day=1)

data = Model.objects.filter(date__gte=lower, date__lt=upper)
```

**Question**

Is there a direct solution to this using django orm or raw query?

Note: *I wanted to know if there is a better way which can save me a few lines of code of manipulating the datetime myself*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. However what you're doing isn't the best way to do it either as using replace can result in some oddities with day lights savings. I'd recommend using `lower = received_date_timezone_aware.date()`.

This assumes `Model.date` is a `DateField`. If it's a datetime, then do this:

```
from datetime import time, datetime

def min_datetime(date: datetime, tz):
    """Get the min datetime of the given datetime and timezone.

    :return datetime: Minimum datetime of the given date.
    """
    return tz.localize(
        datetime.combine(date.astimezone(tz).date(), time.min))


def max_datetime(date: datetime, tz):
    """Get the max datetime of the given datetime and timezone.

    :return datetime: Maximum datetime of the given date.
    """
    return tz.localize(
        datetime.combine(date.astimezone(tz).date(), time.max))

Model.objects.filter(date__range=(min_datetime(value, tz), max_datetime(value, tz)))
```

Comment: Couldn't find `tz.localize` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html . I want data to be returned that has datetime of client specific timezone. looking your answer, this is what I did, `tz = rcvd_date.tzinfo` `lower = datetime.combine(rcvd_date, time.min, tzinfo=tz)` `upper = datetime.combine(rcvc_date, time.max, tzinfo=tz)`. This solved my problem

Comment: The `localize` function is a part of `pytz` timezones.

Comment: Got it... @schillingt